# Setting htaccess rule for nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

Hi i m having issue while setting htaccess rule in nginx. My htaccess is :

htaccess rules are:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I have converted it like this:

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
        rewrite /.* /index.php/$request_uri last;
}
```

I have read that if is evil for nginx but i dont understand these rules. My application which i am trying to setup is:

http://products.cogzidel.com/airbnb-clone/

Now rule is useful when we try to access admin area. We access it by writing /administrator in url and the rules takes this as input for index.php and we login to that. But after applying this rule i see in log that error 404 is coming. Let me mention that nginx vhost is reloading properly after this rule and i have added this rule in server area and loxation area also but nog working

Comment: Don't use online apache->nginx conversion tools. They produce junk config like that in the question. You only need `try_files` for what is asked.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look into the location blocks http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location and the try_files directives http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

For example, if you look at the wordpress blog (a fairly comprehensive example) http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress you'll see this:

```
 location /wordpress {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;
 }
```

which is saying "try the file directly in /wordpress, otherwise pass it across to index.php for processing".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for giving idea about try files. I worked on it and entered this block in location: try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

It worked and not i can access http://my.url.com/administrator

Further the below mentioned stack link is best for understanding try files which helped me as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798457/how-can-i-make-this-try-files-directive-work